# Sum same length array records into new array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bunch of records each with an array of numeric values.

The values must be in arrays because across the entire dataset there is no guarantee that the number of elements is the same, ie I can't split into consistent columns.

However, the significance of the element position and length of each array is the same within a "group" of records, which I need to aggregate.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM day_summary WHERE group_code=1;

summary_date | vals
-------------|--------
2019-04-17   | {0,3,4}
2019-04-18   | {1,3,2}
2019-04-19   | {7,5,1}
```

I need to aggregate into:

```
SELECT extract('month' from summary_date) month,
    what_do_i_do(vals)
FROM day_summary
WHERE group_code=1
GROUP BY 1;

month  | vals
-------|--------
4      | {8,11,7}
```

(posgresql 9.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do that a lot, you can create a custom aggregate for this:

```
create or replace function array_sum(p_one int[], p_two int[])
  returns int[]
as
$$
  select array_agg(coalesce(x1.val,0) + coalesce(x2.val,0))
  from unnest(p_one) with ordinality as x1(val, ix)
    full join unnest(p_two) with ordinality as x2(val, ix) on x1.ix = x2.ix;
$$
language sql
stable;

create aggregate array_sum_agg(int[]) 
(  
  sfunc = array_sum,
  stype = int[],
  initcond = '{}'
);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
SELECT extract('month' from summary_date) as month,
       array_sum_agg(vals)
FROM day_summary
WHERE group_code=1
GROUP BY 1;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/XWD31187

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using unnest to allow the aggregation:

```
select month, array_agg(val ORDER BY pos) FROM
  ( 
    SELECT extract('month' from summary_date) as month, s.pos, sum(s.val) as val
    FROM day_summary,
    LATERAL unnest(day_summary.vals) WITH ORDINALITY s(val, pos)
    GROUP BY month, s.pos
   ) x
GROUP by month;
```

If the arrays are huge or numerous this may not perform that well.  I've recently been working on a Postgres extension which would simplify this (here: https://github.com/tarkmeper/numpgsql) to support numeric calculations directly on arrays.  It includes allowing the sum aggregate to work directly on numeric array types (however you need the ability to build and install extensions).

Comment: Here's your solution in fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q4ocaa4DnPA63gmyJKP5dh/1 `with ordinality` is so neat

Answer (score 0):

another way you can try to use `generate_subscripts`

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.5)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    summary_date date,
    val integer[]
);



INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2019-04-17','{0,3,4}');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2019-04-18','{1,3,2}');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2019-04-19','{7,5,1}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT m,array_agg(val ORDER BY rn)
FROM (
  SELECT  extract('month' from tt.summary_date) m,sum(tt.val[rn]) val,rn
  FROM  T tt
  CROSS JOIN generate_subscripts(tt.val, 1) AS rn
  GROUP BY extract('month' from tt.summary_date),rn
) t1
 group by m;

| m   | array_agg |
| --- | --------- |
| 4   | 8,11,7    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfUPYC55mksbKkgjjmzdky/0)